# Adding a dropped check-constraint what queries the table

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

I'm using a Postgres to preist a hierarchical data set; the table I'm using is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE layers (
    bucket      text not null,
    uniq_id     serial not null,
    name        text not null,
    parent      text,
    value       text,

    constraint layers_pk primary key (bucket, uniq_id)
);
```

The `name` value should be unique in a defined scope, determined by `parent` value. In order to restrict and guarantee this I decided to use a `CONSTRAINT CHECK`, by a function relying on `SELECT` the current state of database.

```
CREATE FUNCTION layers_name_uniqueness_check(bk text, nm text, pr text) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
    DECLARE
        cnt integer;
    BEGIN
        IF pr IS NULL THEN
            SELECT INTO cnt COUNT(*) FROM layers WHERE bucket = bk AND name = nm AND parent IS NULL;
        ELSE
            SELECT INTO cnt COUNT(*) FROM layers WHERE bucket = bk AND name = nm AND parent = pr;
        END IF;
        RETURN cnt = 0;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

ALTER TABLE layers
    ADD CONSTRAINT layers_name_uniqueness
    CHECK (layers_name_uniqueness_check(bucket, name, parent))
;
```

This approach seems working well if provided from the starting point. If I want to apply this `CONSTRAINT CHECK` to a table that has already some records, this approach will not work boviously, as I'm running query on the table, and the given record is already there.

```
INSERT INTO layers (bucket, name, parent, value) VALUES ('bisphone', 'A', null, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO layers (bucket, name, parent, value) VALUES ('bisphone', 'A.A', 'A', 'Hello');

ALTER TABLE layers DROP CONSTRAINT layers_name_uniqueness;

ALTER TABLE layers
    ADD CONSTRAINT layers_name_uniqueness
    CHECK (layers_name_uniqueness_check(bucket, name, parent))
;
```

The Output

```
[23514] ERROR: check constraint "layers_name_uniqueness" is violated by some row
```

I need to know that is it possible to fix this by a trick or should I address the problem (preventing duplicated `name` value in the the determined scope by `parent`) with a different approch. Any help?

Comment: Why are you not enforcing uniqueness with a `UNIQUE` constraint?

Comment: @MichaelKutz The real implementation have a more complex logic inside the function it relies on, though for the published example a `UNIQUE` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `NOT VALID` option to the `ALTER ... ADD CONSTRAINT` statement it's possible to ignore the the validation of the `CONSTRAINT` on the existed data.

```
ALTER TABLE layers
    ADD CONSTRAINT layers_name_uniqueness
    CHECK (layers_name_uniqueness_check(bucket, name, parent))
    NOT VALID
;
```